# How to make the Keyboard show when touching the parent view

Tags: react-native, textinput

I'm creating an app with React Native & Expo.
One of the search inputs includes an icon, so I did it like so:

```
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <FontAwesome name="search" size={20} color="black" />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                value={search}
                placeholder="Pesquise"
                placeholderTextColor={text_gray}
                onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
            />
        </View>
```

But the Keyboard shows only when I click the TextInput, and I need to open it wherever I click the View that wraps it and the icon.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ref to the TextInput and then call REF.current.focus() to focus on the textInput and REF.current.blur() to blur it. Use Pressable instead of View, its just like a View but with different onPress events.

```
const textInput = useRef(null);

return (
  <Pressable style={styles.inputContainer} onPress={() => textInput?.current?.focus()}>
    <FontAwesome name="search" size={20} color="black" />
    <TextInput
      ref={textInput}
      style={styles.input}
      value={search}
      placeholder="Pesquise"
      placeholderTextColor={text_gray}
      onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
    />
  </Pressable>
)
```